# How big online shops store product pages

Tags: database, html, storing-data, online-store

just a question from curiosity. How big online stores with lots of products (can) store their product pages?

I know one solution might be database and then generating the content on demand, but how would they be able to hand URL requests like www.onlinestore.com/productname.htm? (Specificaly I mean this store http://www.alza.cz/pevne-disky/18842851.htm ). Every product links to productname.htm page.

Is it possible (and viable) to have all product pages pregenerated?

Comment: They are most likely using a wildcard routing engine to map <some_id>.htm to a specific product in their catalog. The server is likely running a dynamic language like PHP or ASP.NET to handle requests.

Comment: This can be done with URL rewriting, routing or slugging, for example. Pregenerating is not a good solution, as caching can achieve the same performance benefits and is much simpler to implement.

Comment: @NathanTaylor so (with my knowledge limited to html,php,js,sql and "htaccess" :)... can I IMAGINE it like handling URL request with htaccess and redirecting to something like generateproductpage.php?product=productname and then let PHP pull data from DB?

Comment: @LukášŘádek That's exactly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will vary from vendor to vendor, but typically this is achieved with a combination of custom URL routing, and a server-side, database-driven language like ASP.NET or PHP.

In the case of your example, it is likely that the "18842851" of http://www.alza.cz/pevne-disky/18842851.htm is actually a product Id, and their server is parsing that product Id in order to get the correct product content from a database. With the content in-hand, the server can then return a reusable template.